# unique pairwise distances between any points in the dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr, euclidean-distance

I have a list of ten points with `X` and  `Ỳ` coordinates. I would like to calculate the possible permutations of distances between any two points. Precisely, only one of the distances in 1-2, 2-1 should be present. I have managed to remove the distances of a point with itself. But couldn't achieve this permutation distances.

```
# Data Generation
df <- data.frame(X = runif(10, 0, 1), Y = runif(10, 0, 1), ID = 1:10)

# Temporary key Creation
df <- df %>% mutate(key = 1) 

# Calculating pairwise distances
df %>% full_join(df, by = "key") %>% 
  mutate(dist = sqrt((X.x - X.y)^2 + (Y.x - Y.y)^2)) %>% 
  select(ID.x, ID.y, dist) %>% filter(!dist == 0) %>% head(11)

# Output 
#    ID.x ID.y       dist
# 1     1    2 0.90858911
# 2     1    3 0.71154587
# 3     1    4 0.05687495
# 4     1    5 1.03885510
# 5     1    6 0.93747717
# 6     1    7 0.62070415
# 7     1    8 0.88351690
# 8     1    9 0.89651911
# 9     1   10 0.05079906
# 10    2    1 0.90858911
# 11    2    3 0.27530175
```

How to achieve the expected output shown below?

```
# Expected Output 
#    ID.x ID.y       dist
# 1     1    2 0.90858911
# 2     1    3 0.71154587
# 3     1    4 0.05687495
# 4     1    5 1.03885510
# 5     1    6 0.93747717
# 6     1    7 0.62070415
# 7     1    8 0.88351690
# 8     1    9 0.89651911
# 9     1   10 0.05079906
# 10    2    3 0.27530175
# 11    2    4 0.5415415
```

But this approach is computationally slower compared to `dist()`. Would be happier to listen to faster approaches.

Comment: You might want to add the `filter(ID.x < ID.y)` call to the pipeline.

Comment: Generally not good to use tags just to "get attention". If your question is about data.table or at least uses it, then I think it fits better.

Comment: @Frank Yes, I have used the tag to get some suggestions using `data.table` approaches (I assume they will be usually faster compared to data frame approaches).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `dist` on the data and then process the output into the required format. You can replace `dist` with any other distance function. Here I've used letters rather than numbers as ID to better show what is happening

```
set.seed(42)
df <- data.frame(X = runif(10, 0, 1), Y = runif(10, 0, 1), ID = letters[1:10])

df %>% 
  column_to_rownames("ID") %>% #make the ID the rownames. dist will use these> NB will not work on a tibble
  dist() %>% 
  as.matrix() %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  rownames_to_column(var = "ID.x") %>% #capture the row IDs
  gather(key = ID.y, value = dist, -ID.x) %>% 
  filter(ID.x < ID.y) %>% 
  as_tibble()

   # A tibble: 45 x 3
    ID.x  ID.y      dist
   <chr> <chr>     <dbl>
 1     a     b 0.2623175
 2     a     c 0.7891034
 3     b     c 0.6856994
 4     a     d 0.2191960
 5     b     d 0.4757855
 6     c     d 0.8704269
 7     a     e 0.2730984
 8     b     e 0.3913770
 9     c     e 0.5912681
10     d     e 0.2800021
# ... with 35 more rows
```

`dist` is very fast compared with looping through calculating distances.
The code can probably be made more efficient, by working directly of the `dist` object rather than converting it into a matrix.

Comment: What if we need to use a custom distance function?

Comment: Adding `filter(ID.x < ID.y)` will lead me to the solution. +1 for the faster approach which will be very crucial in case of larger datasets.

Comment: How do you tweak the solution when the `ID` is different from the sequence `1:10`?  Instead of this `rowid_to_column(var = "ID.x")`, I tried using `mutate("ID.x" = df$ID)`. But, I have no clear idea(s) on the alternative(s) for the creation of  `ID.y` in `gather(key = ID.y, value = dist, -ID.x) `.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this is a slightly simpler approach:

```
df <- data.frame(X = runif(10, 0, 1), Y = runif(10, 0, 1), ID = 1:10)

df2 <- data.frame(ID1 = rep(1:10, each = 10),
                  ID2 = 1:10,
                  distance = as.vector(as.matrix((dist(df)))))
```

Then get rid of diagonal:

```
df2 <- df2[df2$ID1 != df2$ID2,]
```

Get rid of upper triangle:

```
df2 <- df2[df2$ID1 < df2$ID2,]
df2
ID1 ID2 distance
2    1   2 1.000615
3    1   3 2.057813
4    1   4 3.010261
5    1   5 4.039502
6    1   6 5.029982
7    1   7 6.035427
8    1   8 7.012540
9    1   9 8.006249
10   1  10 9.015352
13   2   3 1.099245
14   2   4 2.011664
...
```

Comment: It is more or less the same as the [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45613743/4836511). I assume `filter(ID.x < ID.y)` is the key!

Comment: This answer only uses baseR. The previous answer uses (several?) undeclared packages